# gson obfuscation proguard errors

Tags: android, gson, obfuscation, proguard, classcastexception

so Ive read pretty much thousands of threads here and at other places and its still not working for me. 
Its either errors like cannot find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe, or if i use dontwarn on those, it compiles but the gson part returns ClassCastExecption at some point.

Now - I know that serialized classes shuold be marked as -keep in proguard settings, I know about -keepattributes *Annotation* and Signature, however i still fail to obfuscate my code properly.

Attaching my proguard-project.txt

```
-optimizationpasses 2
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic 

-allowaccessmodification
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepattributes Signature

-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class my.package.model.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keep class net.sqlcipher.** {
    *;
}

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** wtf(...);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}
```

Edit 1 
I also checked this [gson example proguard settings](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg)

Comment: Apparently 

    -keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

sorta helped. I aint got any clue why though, and im not getting Logs cut out of the output aswell, it just changed into StringBuffer lol

Comment: You could post this comment as your own answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently -keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated, SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Annotation,EnclosingMethod sorta helped. I aint got any clue why though, and im not getting Logs cut out of the output aswell, it just changed into StringBuffer lol.

Edit 1
Though ive added a target into ant build.xml script that goes like this if anyone needs it

```
<target name="-commentoutlogs">
    <replaceregexp match="(Log\..*?;\s*\n)" replace="/*\1*/" flags="gs" byline="false">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

and to uncomment:

```
    <target name="-uncommentlogsafter">
    <replaceregexp match="\/\*(Log\..*?;\s*\n)\*\/" replace="\1" flags="gs" byline="false">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

so you can add it to like release target so it fixes the stuff for you and the Logs are finely commented into

```
/*Log.<blablabla> );
*/
```